# Htaccess Multi domain, but redirect one domain except a specific path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a multi-domain configured htaccess which means depending on what domain name is entered, the depending content is displayed and is redirected to the https version of whatever domain

A small snippet of my what I tried in my .htacess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^arabme.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.arabme.com$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^chiname.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(landing|marketing)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.greatwall.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

but on `chiname.com` I want to redirect all to `http://www.greatwall.com` except for two folders. `/landing` and `/marketing`.

So whenever a user enters `chiname.com/landing/*.php` or `chiname.com/marketing/*.php` it needs to display without redirecting to the `https://www.greatwall.com` and for every other path regarding `chiname.com` needs to redirect to `https://www.greatwall.com`.

My above would always redirect to `https://www.greatwall.com/` regardless of my rewriteCond when I access any of the `/landing` or `/marketing` folders from `chiname.com`.

**Note** I do not have Server level privileges so I do not have access to the VirtualHost .conf files.

Comment: ....so, what's the problem in writing the specific rules for that?

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried adding a specific rule, please see my edit, and I get redirected.

Comment: Would it not be better to do this in the relevant `<VirtualHost>` directives in `httpd-vhosts.conf` ?

Comment: @CD001 No, I do not have server level privileges, although I could request the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguably it would be better to do this in a `<VirtualHost>` directive in the main *httpd-vhosts.conf* file - but since that's not an option:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^arabme.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.arabme.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^chiname.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(landing|marketing)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.greatwall.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Assuming your `.htaccess` file is at the document root, you just had a couple of errors:

1: you don't need to repeat `RewriteEngine On`

2: you'd missed a `/` after *greatwall.com* in the `RewriteRule` which meant the redirect would go to *https://www.greatwall.comwhatever* rather than *https://www.greatwall.com/whatever*

---

I tested this on [htaccess.madewithlove.be](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=4a9d321a-01bd-5f57-9574-4999d244ddc1) so it *should* work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have been trying and don't seem to get it to work, it just keeps redirecting to `https://www.greatwall.com/$1`

Comment: @SanjokGurung - literally `/$1`? Not the path from `^(.*)$`? You've not put in a backslash rather than a forward slash have you?

Comment: Sorry not literally `/$1` but the path. I am putting everything just as according with your answer. Not a back slash.

Comment: Odd - that *should* redirect everything *unless* the path starts with either /landing or /marketing ... it all checks out on [the htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=c85d8db4-2711-5dcb-8ade-558ab5d336b3) - as long as the .htaccess file is at the docroot.

Comment: Thank you it did work actually, I had a errorDocument redirect at the end of the hosts file which caused the issue but this answers my question.

Comment: If possible I have a new issue if it interests you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54809486/htaccess-redirect-excluded-subfolder-to-https-version-of-domain-and-everything

Thanks