# Htaccess. Redirect excluded subfolder, to https version of domain and everything else gets redirected to another domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, vhosts

I have a multidomain site,

Which means depending on the domain a version of content is displayed,

So for now I have domains `chiname.com` and `greatwall.com`
When a user lands on `chiname.com` gets redirected to `https://www.greatwall.com` except for two folder `/landing` and `/marketing` which stays on `chiname.com` but wanted it to be on the `https` version of `chiname.com`.

I tried adding a rewriteRule, but doesn't work for me

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^chiname.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(landing|marketing)
RewriteRule ^(landing/.*)$ https://www.chiname.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(marketing/.*)$ https://www.chiname.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.greatwall.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use these 2 redirect rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?chiname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(landing|marketing) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?chiname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(landing|marketing) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.greatwall.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Make sure to use a new browser for testing.

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Networking tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Comment: Testing in chrome in incognito mode with caching disabled, I get all 301 errors, all the URLs I get is `https://chiname.com/landing/*` and at the end it fails. Do you want my full htaccess file ??

Comment: Yes I suggest editing your question with full .htaccess and also tell me about your hosting info e.g. Apache version, DocumentRoot, presence of any proxy server etc